# Is there a way to make a line between two coordinates in a map view of MapKit?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have two locations. A current location (=visible) and a target location where the user may want to go to. could I make a line from my current location to the target location? as far as I get it, I can only create annotations. But maybe there's a way to just draw in there?

Comment: just an FYI... this is now possible by using MKPolyline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to create custom class that implements the [MKAnnotation protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

There is some good sample code on doing this to create routes at [The Reluctant Blogger](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108)